# Puzzle question (trick)

Tags: puzzle

Is there a way to proof that this always works:

- Pick 21 different cards;
- Choose one card, and remember it;
- Place the cards on three accumulations (every accumulation is 7 cards);
- Choose the one with your chosen card;
- Pik up the three accumulations with the one with your card on the top;
- Do that another time;
- Than the sixth card is the card you choose.

Comment: Could you clarify the "do that another time" step? I'm not sure which you mean by the repeated step.

Comment: I recommend starting with the cards in order, then doing the whole trick to yourself with all the cards face up, seeing how the cards move around as you proceed. Also do a search on "the twenty-one trick".